# Li-Fi, hardware and software limits

Tags: speed

Yesterday, I saw some new articles about Li-Fi. With speeds up to 1 Gb/s it seems like a very renovating technology.

Can current hardware and/or software can actually handle this kind of speed?
How do they test this kind of speed, and will this require a complete new overhaul on the hardware/software in the future?

It just out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have had 1 Gb, 10 Gb ethernet for a while now, and, more recently, 40 Gb and 100 Gb ethernet. Why would you think that current hardware and software can't handle another 1 Gb technology?

Li-Fi will require some new hardware to transmit and receive since it is based on light instead of radio waves, but it is just an evolution of IEEE standards, not something radically different.

I believe the current Li-Fi really only goes up to 96 Mb, and that is far short of 1 Gb.

Comment: I think OP mispelled 1GB/s ... BeamCaster seems to be able to deliver 1.25GigaBytes per second  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li-Fi  
As an aside question,  is a 100Gbps link really capable of 11 GB/s or there is some limitation due to overheads or whatever?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misspelled the upper case. Then where are the limitations in speed actually (like RobertoP suggest)?

Comment: @RobertoP 100 Gbit/s Ethernet has the same overhead as all Ethernet PHYs - the nominal speed excludes line encoding overhead but includes packet and frame layer overhead. A TCP connection over 100GE can transport 11.866 GB/s with standard frame size with MTU 1500 (20 byte L1, 18 byte L2, 20 byte IP, and 20 byte TCP overhead).